# HTML input prepopulate date

Tags: javascript, html

Am rediscovering HTML after quite some time.

I am using just HTML and javascript along with Salesforce. I have two date input fields.
I was curious to see if there is any easy way to populate these fields with:
a. Today's date
b. Date 6 months before today.

```
<input type="text" id="toDate" size="10" onmouseover="initialiseCalendar(this, 'toDate')"/>
```

Thanks,
Calvin

Comment: What date format do you want to display?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good thing to populate them on mouseover? So, every time the mouse hovers on the field, it sets the inizial date.

Comment: Please ignore the mouseover function. It brings up a calendar to choose a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate with today's date:

```
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("toDate").value = today.getFullYear() + "-"
        + String(today.getMonth() + 101).slice(-2) + "-"
        + String(today.getDate() + 100).slice(-2);
```

6 month in the past:

```
var past = new Date();
past.setMonth(past.getMonth() - 6); //
document.getElementById("toOldDate").value = past.getFullYear() + "-"
        + String(past.getMonth() + 101).slice(-2) + "-"
        + String(past.getDate() + 100).slice(-2);
```

Comment: That's because I copypasted too much :P Fixed now. Forgot to change `today` to `past` once.

Comment: LOL just seen that, we used that same code, but it's to be expected I guess as that's the way to do it :)

Comment: Am marking as answer since u gave me complete code....Also huge thanks to mattytommo....as well.

Answer (score 4):

The following JavaScript sets the `value` of your textbox to today's date, in format yyyy-mm-dd. See how I add 1 to the month? `getMonth()` returns 0-11 for current month, so 1 is added to it:

```
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("toDate").value = today.getFullYear() + "-" +
    parseInt(today.getMonth()+1) + "-" + ​​​​​​today.getDate();​​​​​
```

**DEMO: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk9PL/3)**

It is worth noting though that if the month or day are lower than 10, you'll only get one digit for each of them. Let me know if this is an issue.

**EDIT:** To get 6 months from today, use:

```
var today = new Date();
var past = today.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 6);
```

Comment: There's no need of `parseInt` since the argument is already an integer. Also, Richard said he wanted the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: Thanks mattytommo, any idea how I can get the date 6 months before today?

Comment: @MaxArt Edited to reflect the format, thanks. You do have to have `parseInt` in the above scenario as it's in the middle of a built string, so just doing + 1 for today's date you'll end up with the month 41 :)

Comment: @mattytommo I get your point, but just put the expression between parenthesis: `... + (today.getMonth()+1) + ...`