# HTML Auto change value of date input2 and input3 depending on input1

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, date

I have 3 date inputs:

```
<p>Bill 50%: <input type="date" name="bill50" /> </p>
<p>Bill 30%: <input type="date" name="bill30" /> </p>
<p>Bill 20%: <input type="date" name="bill20" /> </p>
```

I would like to know how to change the value of `bill30` and `bill20` such that it automatically adds 30 days and 60 days respectively to the date on `bill50`.

I tried doing it in PHP to no avail, and because I am a total noob on JavaScript, AJAX and the likes, please bear with me when I ask stupid questions.

Comment: I'm actually a little confused as to what you're asking here, sorry. Can you elaborate a bit? For example, if I put a value into the "bill30" input box what do you want to have happen?

Comment: This could be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705763/html-input-prepopulate-date

Comment: The input is actually a date. It will display a calendar to choose a date. After choosing a date, I want to display the value of bill50 + 30 days to bill30 and bill50 + 60 days to bill 20.

Comment: @Alp sorry but the link you showed me is in the text format. Tried editing it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk9PL/3/) but doesn't seem to work for me. The link shows my edits.

Comment: You are right. Posted an answer that should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an example with the help of some jQuery methods:

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g5JZw/)**

html:

```
<input type="date" id="fromDate" size="10"/>
<input type="date" id="toDate" size="10"/>
```

js:

```
$('#fromDate').on('change', function() {
    var date = new Date($(this).val());
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+20);
    $('#toDate').val(date.toJSON().slice(0,10));
});
```

### Explanation

- `$('#fromDate')` selects the first date chooser
- `.on('change', function() { ... })` fires if a date was chosen and the callback function gets executed
- in this function `$(this)` refers to the date chooser element
- `date.getDate()+20` adds 20 days to the chosen date
- `date.setDate(...)` sets the new date
- `$('#toDate').val(...)` sets the date on the second date chooser
- you cannot call `val(date)` directly because `date` looks like this: `"Tue Jun 04 2013 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)"`
- `date.toJSON()` gives us: `"2013-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"`
- `date.toJSON().slice(0,10)` gives us the first 10 chars: `"2013-06-04"` (which is the format the date input expects)

Comment: Works great! Now I just need to study how this works... +1 for you.

Comment: i added an explanation to my post. feel free to ask if there is anything you dont understand